# Retrieve PHP Records from a server?

Tags: php, database, record, urlretrieve

I have a subscription at https://www.vafinancials.com/v5/vcas/, a closed-source service. From a web control panel, you can bring up Pilot Reports (PIREPs) like this:

```
https://www.vafinancials.com/clientweb/flightlog.php?fn=35e097e62bec9147861a575a8f5a1264&va=18517&fy=2019&fm=11&fd=17
```

But only one at a time.

In that URL, the "fn" is each PIREP's unique address, `va` is constant, `fy/m/d` refer to the date.

With this information and the appropriate login credentials, can someone advise if it is possible to retrieve 1000s of PIREPs en-masse from the site?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the browser rendered source. There you will find a script at the end `./js/flightlog3.js` which upon further inspect relies on the js var `fpath`. Study the url pattern (route) of how `fpath` is defined. It takes this form using your example: `https://www.vafinancials.com/airlines/18517/2019/11/17/35e097e62bec9147861a575a8f5a1264.xml?nr=1193`

The next step would be to write some php code that looped thru creating the necessary urls under this pattern, and fetching each xml file in turn and saving it to a file or database. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Edit:

You would need to know the `fn` ahead of time. Or somehow figure out if there is some sort of way to produce how the `fn` is defined. But with a list of known `fn` and other values in the urls, you would be successful.